# Swap Value for many attribute

Tags: python

How can i swap the value for all attribute?? I want FieldIP = 1. MomentIP=1 FieldOP =3 and so on.

## Table of example

```
FieldIP =3                  FieldOP    =1        
MomentIP =3                 MomentOP   =1  
NormalizeMomentIP =3        NormalizeMomentOP  =1       
ixfwdIP  =3                 ixfwdOP       =1
iyfwdIP  =3                 iyfwdOP       =1
ixbwdIP  =3                 ixbwdOP       =1
iybwdIP  =3                 iybwdOP       =1
MsAvgIP  =3                 MsAvgOP       =1
MsStdIP  =3                 MsStdOP       =1
HkIP     =3                 HkOP          =1
NegFieldIP  =3              NegFieldOP    =1
NegNormalizeMomentIP =3     NegNormalizeMomentOP  =1     
NegFieldBotIP =3            NegFieldBotOPx`       =1
NegNormalizeMomentBotIP =3  NegNormalizeMomentBotOP   =1
```

How can i swap the value for all attribute?? Is there any shorter way? **This is the code i did.** If i did finish all 14 attribute it will be very long as i have to declare 28 variable...

```
    x = FieldIP
    y = FieldOP
    ...
    if ( HkOP > HkIP):
        FieldOP = x
        FieldIP = y
        print "Swapped"
```

## Result i want

```
FieldIP =1                  FieldOP    =3       
MomentIP =1                 MomentOP   =3  
NormalizeMomentIP =1        NormalizeMomentOP  =3       
ixfwdIP  =1                 ixfwdOP       =3
iyfwdIP  =1                 iyfwdOP       =3
ixbwdIP  =1                 ixbwdOP       =3
iybwdIP  =1                 iybwdOP       =3
MsAvgIP  =1                 MsAvgOP       =3
MsStdIP  =1                 MsStdOP       =3
HkIP     =1                 HkOP          =3
NegFieldIP  =1              NegFieldOP    =3
NegNormalizeMomentIP =1     NegNormalizeMomentOP  =3     
NegFieldBotIP =1            NegFieldBotOPx`       =3
NegNormalizeMomentBotIP =1  NegNormalizeMomentBotOP   =3
```

Comment: Where are you getting all these attributes from? Are they stored in a file, part of a class, (?)?

Answer (score 2):

swap two variable in short way

```py
a, b = b, a
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this data of yours is in a text file of some sort.

Try something like this:

```
import re
# read your data
lines = open('mytable.txt').readlines()
# regex to capture your 'values'
regex = re.compile(r'(.*?=)([0-9]+)(.*?=)([0-9]+)')
for line in lines:
    # for each line, match the value groups and substitute swapped values
    print regex.sub(r'\1\4\3\2', line)
```

Should print the table with swapped values, and preserve the whitespace too.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through local vars to do so:

```
key = key2 = None
for key in locals():
    if key.endswith('OP'):
        key2 = key[:-2] + 'IP'
        if locals()[key] > locals()[key2]:
            locals()[key], locals()[key2] = locals()[key2], locals()[key]
            print 'swapped'
```

*You have to declare `key` and `key2` before the for loop, not inside it.*